# How can I generate the random alphanumeric string in specific order on a plane?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

Is it possible to generate a random alphanumeric string in specific order. The order should be something like "GS-11-005-0263", but should be randomly generated. For example, the first two alphabets are randomly chosen between A-Z and then this specific character "-" and then two random numbers from 0-9 and then "-" and three random numbers from 0-9 followed by "-" and then again four random numbers from "0-9".

Help in this regard would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Please forgive me, I think you were just looking for a solution for *Python*, but so that others can find this topic in the *Geometry Nodes* section, I added another tag here.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

```
import bpy, random, string

a0 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters).upper()
a1 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters).upper()

b = "{:0>2d}".format(random.randint(0, 99))
c = "{:0>3d}".format(random.randint(0, 999))
d = "{:0>4d}".format(random.randint(0, 9999))

s = f'{a0}{a1}-{b}-{c}-{d}'
print(s)

bpy.ops.object.text_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
obj = bpy.context.object
obj.data.body = s
```

Additional

```
import bpy, random, string, math
from mathutils import Vector, Quaternion, Matrix

def gen_text_with_light_cam(text_size, light_pos, cam_pos):
    a0 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters).upper()
    a1 = random.choice(string.ascii_letters).upper()

    b = "{:0>2d}".format(random.randint(0, 99))
    c = "{:0>3d}".format(random.randint(0, 999))
    d = "{:0>4d}".format(random.randint(0, 9999))

    s = f'{a0}{a1}-{b}-{c}-{d}'
    print(s)

    bpy.ops.object.text_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
    obj = bpy.context.object
    data = obj.data
    data.body = s
    data.size = text_size
    bpy.context.view_layer.update()
    data.offset_x = - obj.dimensions[0] / 2
    data.offset_y = - obj.dimensions[1] / 2

    bpy.ops.object.light_add(type='POINT', radius=1, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
    light = bpy.context.object
    light.location = light_pos

    bpy.ops.object.camera_add(enter_editmode=False, align='VIEW', location=(0, 0, 0), rotation=(0.457107, 0.00384698, -0.542516), scale=(1, 1, 1))
    cam = bpy.context.object
    cam.location = cam_pos
    bpy.context.view_layer.update()

    loc, rot, sca = get_rot_mat(Vector(cam_pos), Vector((0,0,0))).decompose()

    old_mode = cam.rotation_mode
    cam.rotation_mode = 'QUATERNION'
    cam.rotation_quaternion = rot
    cam.rotation_mode = old_mode

def get_rot_mat(v1, v2):
    z = v1 - v2
    x = Vector((-z.y, z.x, 0)) / pow(z.y * z.y * z.z * z.z, 0.5)
    y = z.cross(x)

    return Matrix((
        (x.x, y.x, z.x, 0),
        (x.y, y.y, z.y, 0),
        (x.z, y.z, z.z, 0),
        (0, 0, 0, 1)))

def clear_scene():
    try:
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
        bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False, confirm=False)
    except:
        pass

def random_1_1():
    return 1 if random.random() < 0.5 else -1

def random_up_pos_by_radius(radius):
    z = random.random() * radius
    a = radius * radius - z * z
    x = random.random() * pow(a, 0.5)
    y = pow(a - x * x, 0.5)
    return (x * random_1_1(), y * random_1_1(), z)


clear_scene()
gen_text_with_light_cam(
    text_size = 1,
    light_pos = random_up_pos_by_radius(16),
    cam_pos = random_up_pos_by_radius(16)
)
```

Comment: why not directly `d = random.randint(0, 9999)`? it's the same effect.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Probably leading zeros ("0001" vs "1")

Comment: @DavidMulder oh good point i totally forgot. thanks!

Comment: How about if we want to clear the frame for the next random generation with different lighting conditions, camera position, and font size?

Comment: Do you mean automatically change the body of the text object when the light/camera position are changed?

Comment: I mean at every next iteration over the number of images we want to generate the output gives us new text with different camera/light position. I general we could have control over camera. lightening and font size of the the text.

Comment: @Zahak Anjum  
 I added some code you can refer to.

Answer (score 3):

This way you can solve it with *Geometry Nodes*:

[image]

Here I create different values with `Random Value`, with which I slice on the one hand a string consisting of letters, and on the other hand a number which corresponds to the length of the necessary digits.

There are of course other ways to solve this, but this example should be a good starting point.

And yes, I know that wasn't the question, but I just felt like it.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Comment: What if you want to add it to on specific plane and clear the frame for every next random generation with different lightening, camera position and font size?

Comment: @ZahakAnjum You could use the node `Scene Time` as a seed value, and thus also control the font size. Alternatively you could control these values via a *Group Input* and *Drivers*.